# How to update nested item in GraphQL wp-graphql

Tags: graphql, wp-graphql

I am trying to edit one of Custom Post Types `Ranking` so that the upvotes field inside `Ranking` > `ranking` > `rankingsPost` > `upvotes` = 1. I cannot seem to do this with a mutation in wp-graphql.

```
mutation MyMutation {
  __typename
  updateRanking(input: {clientMutationId: "UpdateRanking", id: "cmFua2luZzo4NjI=", title: "Jamie"}) {
    ranking {
      rankingsPost {
        upvotes
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However this is not an option with graphQL it appears. As you can see, the upvotes is nested inside the Ranking custom post type.

[image]

Comment: could you please explain more? what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have updated the question to hopefully add a bit more insight. I will ad more details if you feel it will help :D